# Lock an auto-populated field in an infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I followed the instructions on creating an auto-populate field that queries via form load, used this site: http://spvee.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/auto-populate-user-information-in-infopath-with-claims-based-authentication-part-1-of-3/

Works well.
However, after form entry, another user must edit (update) the form with status/notes and the user lookup that auto-populates changes to that user's name.  How can I lock the auto-populated field after initial entry?  InfoPath does not recognize this field as a "field" so no rules can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Add another field that does not show to the users. Once the user field is set on form load, set this hidden field to "Set" or something and then just check that on load in an if condition. "If hidden field is blank then set user". I do this on other fields as well.